# Functional equation involving sine function: $ \sin x + f ( x ) = \sqrt 2 f \left( x - \frac \pi 4 \right) $

Tags: trigonometry, functional-equations

> Let $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a continuous function such that
> $$ \sin x + f ( x ) = \sqrt 2 f \left( x - \frac \pi 4 \right) \text . $$
> Find $ f $.

I noticed that a solution for $ f $ is the cosine function. I don't know how to continue. Is there a way I could link it to d'Alembert functional equation?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no assumption on $f$? At least continuity? Because in that case we can take arbitrary function on $[0, \pi/4)$ and extend its values on the real line using initial equation. So without assumptions on $f$ there are $2^c$ solutions for this equation

Comment: Is f integrable?

Comment: How can you calculate $f(\pi/4)$ if the function is defined only on rational numbers?

Comment: @Virtuoz Excuse me, it is continuous function.

Comment: Please add this to the question to avoid any misunderstanding for people reading this post

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - \cos x$. We have
$$\sin x + \cos x + g(x) = \sqrt 2 \cos \left( x - \frac \pi 4 \right)
+ \sqrt 2 g \left( x - \frac \pi 4 \right)$$
which yields
$$g(x) = \sqrt 2 g \left( x - \frac \pi 4 \right) \tag {*} \label { * }$$
Now note that every function $g$ satisfying \eqref{ * } gives a solution for the original equation by adding $\cos x$. There are a lot of such functions since **every** function $g_0 : [ 0 , \frac \pi 4 ) \to \mathbb R$ can be extended uniquely to a $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfying \eqref{ * }. Further assumptions like continuity or differentiability give you some conditions on $g_0$, especially some conditions concerning the value $g_0 (x)$ near $x = 0$ and $x = \frac \pi 4$. But these assumptions are not strong enough to force $g (x) = 0$.

Comment: $(*)$ has a natural solution of $g(x)=ab^x$ where $a=g(0)$ and $b=4^{1/\pi}$, giving $f(x)= \cos(x)+(f(0)-1)4^{x/\pi}$.  There are other solutions too, such as any of the form $f(x)= \cos(x)+h(x)4^{x/\pi}$ where $h(x)$ is periodic with $h\left(x\right)=h\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ and continuous or differentiable if you require $f(x)$ to be.  Is this the most general form?

Comment: @Henry Yes it is. Every $g$ gives you a unique $h$ (defined with the equation $h(x) = g(x) \cdot 4 ^ {- \frac x \pi}$), and vice versa; and every $f$ corresponds to a unique $g$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Can you assume that $f''$ exist? In this case note that is is suffices to prove that there exist a function $g$ such that 
$g(x)=\sqrt{2}g(x-\frac{\pi}{4})$ since 
$$
-\sin x+f''(x)=\sqrt{2}f''\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
$$
Hence 
$$
(f+f'')(x)=\sqrt{2}(f+f'')\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
$$

Comment: No, you can't make this assumption. At most, you could consider $f: \Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q$ if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Write the eqn like this.
$${1\over \sqrt 2}\sin x+{1\over \sqrt 2}f(x)=f(x-{\pi\over 4})$$
$$\sin {\pi\over 4}\sin x+\cos {\pi\over 4}f(x)=f(x-{\pi\over 4})$$

Does it look familiar? The procedure in solving such problems is to modify values so as to make them look familiar..

Comment: Should I make some substitutions?

Comment: @I.Stefan Substitutions for what?

Comment: To substitute $x \to x- \frac {\pi} {4}$ to continue?

Comment: I am not a professional in solving such equations.

Comment: @I.Stefan Doesn't the 4 formulas of sine and cosine come to mind when when you see the ${1\over \sqrt 2}$ and the sine functions?

Comment: Yes, but I have $f(x)$ instead of $x$.

Comment: @I.Stefan So think which one sine or cosine would fit in place of $f(x)$ so as to make the equation correct. Only 4 options... Not too hard

Comment: Yes, I got it, but does this assure me that the cosine function is the only solution to the equation?

Comment: @I.Stefan No.that you might post as another different question as "How do guarantee how many solution this eqn has." And please upvote if you liked my answer

Comment: My question "find $f$" implies that you should find all the possible values of function $f$. The proof that cosine function is a solution is insufficient.